# POST request returning 500 Internal Server Error Next.js

Tags: post, error-handling, next.js13, http-status-code-500, server-error

I am trying to write a simple POST request in my next.js app and getting a 500 Internal Server error when testing in Postman.  I've written a GET request and that works fine.

Here is my basic code.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const body = await request.json();
  return NextResponse.json(body);
};
```

Here is the error in my terminal:
⨯ SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 31
at JSON.parse ()
at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5329:19)
at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5300:27)
at fullyReadBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1447:9)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async specConsumeBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5309:7)
at async POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/projects/route.ts:11:18)
at async /Users/austinwilliams/Desktop/portfolio-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63251

I've tried removing the async and await, that will remove the error but the response is an empty object.  Not sure how to troubleshoot knowing it is a promise and the function needs to by async.

When I remove the async await I get status 200 with an empty response object.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const body = request.body;
  return NextResponse.json(body);
}
```

Comment: I got a status 200 but the object in the response is empty.

Comment: The code copies the body from the request to the response. Did you provide a body?

Comment: I see in your screenshot  "John Doe"" has an extra quote. Can it be a problem with the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

My JSON object in postman had a syntax error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).